# Retrieving child's folder data Firebase Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently building a project that lists various of restaurants. In my project I use main table view to show the list of restaurants and upon clicking cell it transfers by segue to the View Controllers that shows basic informations about the restaurant. In the detail View Controller there is a button named "Offers", upon clicking it opens another tableview that shows an array of offers of that restaurant. (please see attached image)

By now I can only retrieve my a list of restaurants with the details showed in detail View Controller, but I have no idea how to show the list of offers for each restaurant. 
Please help me and thank you in advance.

**Codes:
Restaurant/Bar model:**

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

struct Bar{
    let id: String
    let barName: String
    let barAddress: String
    let barMainImage: String
    let barInfo: String
    let barFullAddress: String
    let averagePrice: String

    let disabledIcon: String
    let parkingIcon: String
    let wifiIcon: String
    let offerImage: String

    static func bar(from snapshot: DataSnapshot) -> Bar?{
        let barDict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]
        guard let barName = barDict["bar_name"] as? String,
        let barAddress = barDict["bar_short_address"] as? String,
        let barMainImage = barDict["bar_main_image"] as? String,
        let barInfo = barDict["bar_info"] as? String,
        let barFullAddress = barDict["bar_full_address"] as? String,
        let averagePrice = barDict["average_price"] as? String,

        let disabledIcon = barDict["disabled_icon"] as? String,
        let parkingIcon = barDict["parking_icon"] as? String,
        let wifiIcon = barDict["wifi_icon"] as? String,
 let offers = barDict["offers"] as? [String:Any],
    let offerImage = offers["offer_image"] as? String,
        let id = String(snapshot.key)
        else {return nil}
    let bar = Bar (id: id, barName: barName, barAddress: barAddress, barMainImage: barMainImage, barInfo: barInfo, barFullAddress: barFullAddress, averagePrice: averagePrice, disabledIcon: disabledIcon, parkingIcon: parkingIcon, wifiIcon : wifiIcon, offerImage: offerImage)

    return bar
}
```

}

**First Table View Controller - that lists all the restaurants:**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage
import SDWebImage

class MainTableVC: UITableViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var MenuBar: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBOutlet weak var cityButton: UIButton!

var ref: DatabaseReference!
var bars = [Bar]()
var selectedBar: Bar?
var refreshTableView = UIRefreshControl()
var selectedCity:String!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()

    //back button title removal
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: nil, action: nil)


    // SlideOutMenu
    MenuBar.target = self.revealViewController()
    MenuBar.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())

    ref = Database.database().reference()

    fetchBars()
    // for pull to refresh
    refreshTableView.tintColor = UIColor.white
    self.tableView.addSubview(refreshTableView)
    refreshTableView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MainTableVC.refreshData), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)


}


// for pull to refress
func refreshData() {
    //removes data before updating and entering new one
    self.bars.removeAll()
    ref.child("Paris").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let bar = Bar.bar(from: snapshot) else {return}
        self.bars.append(bar)
        self.refreshTableView.endRefreshing()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
 }

func fetchBars(){

    ref.child("Paris").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let bar = Bar.bar(from: snapshot) else {return}
        self.bars.append(bar)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
    self.refreshTableView.endRefreshing()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return bars.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RestoCell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerCell

    let bar = bars[indexPath.row]
    cell.RestName.text = bar.barName
    cell.RestAddress.text = bar.barAddress
    cell.RestImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: bar.barMainImage))


    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedBar = bars[indexPath.row]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "DetailView", sender: self)
}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "DetailView", let bar = selectedBar{
        let detailVC = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
        detailVC.selectedBar = bar
    }
}
```

**Detail View Controller - that list all the detail information for each restaurant:**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage
import SDWebImage

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var MyScroll: UIScrollView!




@IBOutlet weak var RestDetailView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var restName: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var restTypeOfFood: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var restClockImage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var restOpenHours: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var restInfoView: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var averagePrice: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var InfoAboutRest: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var FullAddressLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var disabledIcon: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var parkingIcon: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var wifiIcon: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var OpeningHoursLabel: UILabel!





@IBOutlet weak var ImageViewD: UIImageView!
```

var selectedBar: Bar?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.RestDetailView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    self.RestDetailView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    self.restInfoView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    self.restInfoView.layer.borderWidth = 1

    if let bar = selectedBar{
        restName.text = bar.barName
        ImageViewD.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: bar.barMainImage))
        InfoAboutRest.text = bar.barInfo
        averagePrice.text = bar.averagePrice
        FullAddressLabel.text = bar.barFullAddress
        disabledIcon.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: bar.disabledIcon))
        parkingIcon.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: bar.parkingIcon))
        wifiIcon.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: bar.wifiIcon))

    }

}






/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

}

**IMAGES**

[Firebase Tree][1]
[MainStoryBoard][2]

```
OffersTableView:


import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage
import SDWebImage


class OffersTableVC: UITableViewController {
var ref: DatabaseReference!
var bars = [Bar]()
var selectedBar: Bar?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    fetchBars()
}
func fetchBars(){

    ref.child("aktau").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let bar = Bar.bar(from: snapshot) else {return}
        self.bars.append(bar)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 1
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OfferCell", for: indexPath) as! OffersTableViewCell

    let bar = bars[indexPath.row]
    cell.offerImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: bar.offerImage))
    return cell
}
```

**Errors in my model:**

[ModelError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QXZv.png)

Comment: There is entirely too much code in the question. The answer may be very simple but without seeing your Firebase structure it's just guesswork. Please include a snippet of your Firebase structure as text please, no images (Firebase Console->Export JSON) and also reduce the code to a minimal example. Take a minute and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Clean it up and we'll take a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must parse the "offers" like

```
let offers = barDict["offers"] as? [String:Any]
```

And then you must parse this Dictionary like

```
    var offersArray = [Offer]()

    for item in offers {

    guard let offerimage = item["offerImage"] as? String, ... {
      var offer = Offer(offerimage)
      offersArray.append(offer)
    }
}


class Offer {

 let offerImageUrl:String
 // Other Properties

   init(string: offerImageUrl){
     self.offerImageUrl = offerImageurl
     //Other Properties
   }
}
```

I hope you get my idea. Now you have an array with your offers :)

Comment: Shall I create a Struct for the Offers? or I should write straight after "let wifiIcon = barDict["wifi_icon"] as? String,"?

Comment: straight after Wifiicon is fine

Comment: I've updated my codes with the edits) but unfortunately, it does not show anything now) even my restaurants list) I dont know why)

Comment: feeling dumb now for asking extra questions ) shall include var offersArray = [offer]() and etc. within my Bar model or in my Offers Table view? ) sorry for disturbing you) I am new to programming)

Comment: let the data in your model. and there aren't dumb questions ;-) i'm here to help you

Comment: still not really working ( added an image with all errors (